# What should be a component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js, components

I am struggling with myself about what needs to be a component?

For example:

- I have a page where everything within is relevant only to itself.
- I have a text input on every form control; Do I need to wrap this in a component? But every place will need a different kind of validation and other stuff related only to it, so why do this?

Usually, when it comes to forms, only the style is the same so why we need to wrap this in a component? We can just share the style with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The *tl;dr;* is that a component is a reusable, encapsulated piece. It's similar to [Brad Frost's Atomic Design](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/). This is not rocket science, different people may split their apps into different components.

That said, there are more than enough tutorials/articles that will help you to understand when to create a component. To get you started:

- https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/step-by-step-guide-to-building-react-redux-apps-using-mocks-48ca0f47f9a
- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: i agreed with that

Answer (score 1):

Reasons where you will want to split into a component:

1. Reuse code across multiple files/parts of your code.
2. Encapsulate the complexity of certain code so that fellow developers can use it without needing to understand its implementation details; just need to look at `props`.
3. You need to do stuff within specific lifecycle hooks, e.g. do certain stuff in `componentDidUpdate` when the component updates.
4. You want to [optimize](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action) the rendering and have to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` for certain parts of your code.